# In Arifureta, how many of Hajime's classmates have died by the end of the first anime season?

Tags: arifureta

Hajime kills Yukitoshi Shimizu after Shumizu brought an entire demon army to kill their sensei. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2k_pfPTE7k

Meld Loggins nearly dies but is saved by Hajime's holy water.

Has any of Hajime's other classmates died?

Comment: I'm watching it, did the first season end?

Comment: It's only Shimizu by the end of the first season.